# Error in Custom Google Tag Manager JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Trying to setup a custom JavaScript in GTM where the innerHTML value is checked for X and if it is X fires.

Here's what I have so far but it's not firing correctly

```
function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('ltrNumPlaceholder');
  if (el == null) return 0;
  return parseInt(el.innerHTML);
 }
```

I also tried this but GTM complains there there is a syntax error on a line that doesn't exist. (GTM error message for the below is: "*Error at line 5, character 2: Parse error. ')' expected.*")

```
function(){
   var stepNum = document.getElementById('ltrNumPlaceholder').innerHTML;
   if(stepNum == 2)return parseInt(stepNum);
};
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: To circumvent the problem you could use a DOM macro for the element with the id "trNumPlaceholder" and then a lookup table macro based on that.

Answer (score 5):

To fix the error message, just remove your semicolon at the end of the function (after the closing curly bracket), and that should work.